# File Upload control inside GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two file upload controls inside GridViewControl for uploading files, I have a button for uploading files inside gridview, I am using its RowCommandEvent for uploading files. How can I get values of fileupload controls in RowCommandEvent?
This is my GridView

```
   <asp:GridView ID="DgFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="DgFiles_RowCommand">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Crime" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>                                               
                                        <asp:Label ID="category" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %>'                                ></asp:Label><br/>                                                
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="file1" runat="server" /><br />
                                        <asp:FileUpload ID="file2" runat="server" />
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnupload" runat="server" CommandName="upload" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbldate" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Date") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblcity" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "City") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>                                      
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

and my RowCommandEvent

```
 protected void DgFiles_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "upload")
            {
            }
        }
```

I have to display records in GridView like structure, with file upload control inside it, If there is alternate way I can do it, kindly suggest.

Comment: http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/file-upload-in-gridview-1008.aspx

Comment: I have seen this, this control have single upload control, I am having separate controls for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,
 You have to add a command column with command name upload
second,

You have to find the control inside the row by using parent property.

```
FileUpload fl1 = (FileUpload)e.Row[rowindex].Cells<cellindex>.FindControl("File1")
FileUpload fl2 = (FileUpload)e.Row[rowindex].Cells<cellindex>.FindControl("File2")
```

Now You can use `fl1` and `fl2` as your filecontrols.